# Using matlab package folder notation in Atlassian Bitbucket

Tags: git, matlab, repository, bitbucket-server

I'm currently moving a large Matlab project into the Atlassian tool suite to manage the development process. The project uses the +folder and @class notation for matlab functions and classes. However when i migrate these into Bitbucket, Atlassian's git server, and try to open a folder in the repository which has a '+' at the start of it's name, i get an error saying "Page not found. We couldn't find the page you requested".

Has anyone experienced this or know a way to fix it?

To clarify I mean when I try to open the repository while using the Bitbucket tool in a web browser, not the local copy of the repository on my machine.

Comment: It works on a [GitHub repo of mine](https://github.com/erikhuizinga/Bland-Altman-Analysis/tree/TM/%2Bsubmodules). Note that the URL contains `%2B` instead of a `+`, you could try that.

Comment: The server is being hosted privately within the company. Someone has suggested with it being windows based rather than linux, that could be causing the issue. I don't know enough about this topic to know how or why. Any ideas?

Comment: The + character is usually allowed on Windows machines. It could be the different directory separator (being `\ ` instead of `/`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague managed to fix this so I'm not sure of the exact details, but what I've been told was that because our bitbucket server was windows based rather than Linux, apparently the latest IIS has tighter restrictions on special characters. He said he allowed double escaping in the application and it now seems to be working. Hope this helps anyone else if they have the same issue.